# Derivative self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

1)I have  the  symbol $\circ$ ?

In  $-(\mathcal{L} \psi)\circ \psi^{-1}$

How to read it  in math in this case ?

2)The derivative of $q(y)=-(\mathcal{L} \psi(x)) $  is
$q^\prime(y)= \frac{-{[\mathcal{L}\psi]}^\prime(x)]} {\psi^\prime (x)}$

I am trying to get but I can not ? Can you help  to obtain the  $q^\prime(y)= \frac{-{[\mathcal{L}\psi]}^\prime(x)]} {\psi^\prime (x)}$, please ?

where $y=\psi(x) =\int_0^x 1/\sqrt{(a(z)}dz$, $x\in (0,\infty)$  and
$\mathcal{L}$ is the non-positive self-adjoint operator.
Thanks.

Comment: $\circ$ means "composed with". In this case, $(-(\mathcal{L} \psi) \circ \psi^{-1}) (x) = -(\mathcal{L} \psi)(\psi^{-1}(x))$.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your answer.

Comment: feel free to upvote my comment if it was helpful

Comment: How I can do that ?

Comment: There should be a triangle above a little flag to the left of my comment. But I just realized, I don't know if you actually need to have a certain amount of reputation to be able to upvote.

Comment: no, problem next time.